# Why is the navigation bar different when viewed in the Xcode storyboard and on a device?

Tags: ios, xcode

When I arrange content on the storyboard in landscape view it looks like this:

[image]

But when I view it on the simulator it looks like this:

[image]

I have tried to alter the settings in simulated metrics but I cannot get the navigation bar to look identical. I am viewing it as iPhone SE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What's the point of your question? The "Back" button?
It's added automatically, because your ViewController is embedded to UINavigationController. If you don't need back button, you can do this in code. Add this to viewDidLoad of your ViewController:

```
self.navigationItem.hidesBackButton = true
```

Comment: The point of my question is that I don't want a big gap between the slider and the bottom bar. I want a back button but I also want to use up the screen space. The storyboard views take up all the vertical space but in the simulator there is a big gap. In a nutshell, why does the navigation bar look bigger on the storyboard than on the simulator?

Comment: Because navigation bar has height = 44 in portrait mode, and height = 32 in landscape mode. 
You should pin slider to bottom using constraint if you need to fix this gap constant.
Storyboard renders navbar constant height in portrait and landscape

Comment: I tried that Anton. But then I get a big gap (on the simulator but not on the storyboard) between the slider and the red view.  I thought the whole point about storyboards was that they enabled you to see how the content would look on an actual device.

Comment: In than case you have options: pin red view to slider, so height of red view will grow when device rotates. Or you can create your custom navigation bar - add UIView to the top of scene, pin to top, left, right, and fix the height.